# Infinite Scroll and Lightzap lightbox for appended items not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I've been working on this tumblr theme

http://pncawebteam.tumblr.com/

Everything works fine on the intially loaded items, but when the infinite scroll appends new photo posts they don't have the lightzap lightbox applied. How do I re-trigger that library after those new items load? Here is my stuff for the appending and the libraries I am using.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pnca.edu/tumblr_assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="http://pnca.edu/tumblr_assets/js/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="http://pnca.edu/tumblr_assets/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

var $container = $('#posts');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 30,
    "gutter": 5
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '.jump_page',    
  nextSelector : '#newContent a',  
  itemSelector : '.item',     
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
    });
  }
);

 });
```

Comment: Hi, there is no code relating to the lightbox? You would do the call back for the `$newElems` inside: `$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){ ... });`